# What will report an account's permissions?

Tags: windows, winapi, permissions

My service program executes another instance of itself with, essentially, `CreateProcess(GetCommandLine())`. The child process then uses `OpenProcess` to get a handle to its parent process (so it can detect when the parent has stopped running). For some customers, `OpenProcess` fails with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. I'm trying to determine the reason and reproduce the circumstances for in-house testing.

I want something I can send to customers (either a program, or instructions for using programs that are already commonly installed on Windows servers) for them to run and generate a report that includes what account the service runs as and what privileges that account and its groups have been granted or denied. How can I collect that information from customers?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the account name is easy -- `GetUserName`. Getting the rights assigned to that account is a bit more work. If memory serves, the sequence runs something like:

```
GetKernelObjectSecurity(Current_oject, &security_descriptor)
GetSecurityDescriptorDacl(security_descriptor, &dacl)
GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(dacl, user_name, &rights)
```

You might prefer to use `GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl` for that last step. There is one problem with all this: if they've restricted the user too much, some (or all) of it might fail as well.

Comment: I might be able to work with this. But what kernel object would I pass to GetKernelObjectSecurity? I'm guessing GetCurrentProcess, since I want to know what the current process is allowed to do. MSDN says I need READ_CONTROL permission in order to call this function, but that shouldn't be an issue since the process is requesting information about itself, right?

Comment: Yes, you'd want the current process handle (I think). Yes, I think you'll almost always have permission to view that, but it's hard to say -- it's *probably* possible to set up some permissions to prevent even that.